# Refresh SESSION after change it by submit form

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, session

I have code that get me country flag for user when select country from drop down menu like this

Submit country:

```
<select name="countryname" onchange="this.form.submit();fla(this);" >
    <option value="AF">Afghanistan</option>
    <option value="US">USA</option>
    <option value="UK">UK</option>
</select>
```

After change above we do this:

```
define('WCDP_PATH_INCLUDES', dirname(__FILE__) . '/inc');

if (!class_exists('GeoIP')) {
    include(WCDP_PATH_INCLUDES . "/geoip.inc");
}
$geo_data = geoip_open(WCDP_PATH_INCLUDES . "/GeoIP.dat", GEOIP_STANDARD);

$country_code = geoip_country_code_by_addr($geo_data, $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);

$countrynameselect =  $_SESSION['countryname'];

if ($countrynameselect) {
    $country_code = $countrynameselect;
} else {
    $country_code = geoip_country_code_by_addr($geo_data, $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);
}       
// Build HTML for flag icons.
?>

<img src="<? bloginfo('stylesheet_directory')?>/flags/sm/<?php echo strtolower($country_code).'.png'; ?>" border="0" style="margin-top:10px" id="flagc" />
```

Now when user select country from drop down menu, I save country post in `SESSION`, But when user change again, it does not update `SESSION`, and to update it, we must refresh page to show new `SESSION` value.

What can I do ??

Comment: You could use ajax to fire up some php script that changes the $_SESSION['countryname']; when the client changes the country in dropdown menu.

Comment: It would be usefull if you put in your question the code for the dropdown menu also.

Answer (score 0):

You can try unset the session and set the session again when a user selects something else.

How are you setting the session? does the user click submit and then the session is set? or are you using AJAX?

Comment: how can unset then set session  value ? try place my code!!

Comment: unset($_SESSION['countryname']; 
and then you can set the session again using your code

Comment: You dont have to unset the session to update it. But in order to update it when client changes dropdown menu you need ajax if you dont want to refresh the page.

Comment: @AliShaikh i try unset($_SESSION['countryname']); in above code but its delete value of new session . its not true way

Comment: @Redrif how can refesh page ?

Comment: @ZamalekMan Could you please post the code which you are using to set the session please. It will help us give a better answer

Comment: @Zamalek Man you said that the session is update after refreshing the page. If you dont want to stay it that way, you have to use ajax that uses another php file where you update the session variable and that ajax triggers when client changes the country. Put here the code for the dropdown menu and i will put answer for you. But i need to know how it looks.

Comment: @ZamalekMan Could you also post the code which sets the session please based on the selection made by the user.

Comment: @Zamalek Man please show us whole file/files that you are using. If you provide us more code we can understand better where is the problem exactly.